# How do I bind data provided by a WCF Webservice to a DataGridView in an Windows Forms Application (C#)?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am having a -probably trivial- issue with my Software Project.
I wrote a simple WebService that is supposed to provide a program I am writing with data from a database.
This program is a Windows Forms Application which displays a number of DataGridViews in MDI Childs. Unfortunately I am unable to bind the data to the GridView. In previous projects I displayed data in a aspx website, and used a ObjectDataSource to bind the data. This however does not seem to be available in Windows Forms Applications. When I try to use the BindingSource Object the table headers are applied, but no data is shown.

Thank you for your help,
Alexander

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what code to post. What would you like to see? I've added a ServiceReference to my WebService that is delievering the data. Not I am trying to create the BindingSource to display the data from the WebService in a DataGridView.